# Free AutoCAD blocks

Tags: autocad

I'm looking to tap into the AutoCAD knowledge base on this site.  I conducted a quick Goolgle search for free AutoCAD blocks, and it returned 762,000 hits.  Certainly, I can find several viable options, but I'm hoping some CAD users can post some "**good**" sites for me to visit, instead of having to waste valuable time researching numerous sites.  Just because a link is at the top of a Google search does not make it a good site, it might just mean it's well coded.  Someone who knows what they're doing can put almost anything near the top of Google searches. I'm hoping for a few "all-in-one" suggestions.

I'm looking for some variety (ie - different types of trees, fire hydrants, doorways, closet doors, industrial symbols/signage, etc, etc, etc).  Basically, I am for looking many different genres of block types - greyscale & colour, recreational/cartoon style blocks (ie - mens/ladies washrooms, snowmobile trails, etc), industrial and professional design style blocks, and so on.  Lastly, I would really like to have the capacity to preview and select individual blocks as opposed to having to download entire packages or bundles.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have looked into the autodesk design center?
Also as an install option there are several hundred MB of symbols in the materials library.
If this isn't enough...
sorry I'll have to return later.